# xgboost in R providing unexpected prediction

Tags: r, tree, prediction, xgboost

Below is a code that produces a simple xgboost model to show the issue I've been seeing. Once the model has been built, we predict using this model and take the second row in our data. If we take the log of relative difference between prediction of the 10th and 9th model, it should give us the prediction for the 10th tree: 0.00873184 in this case.

Now if we use the input to the tree (matrix "a" which has value 0.1234561702 for row 2) and run through the model, we expect a prediction of 0.0121501638. However, it looks like after the second split (<0.123456173) it takes the wrong direction and ends up at the node with 0.00873187464 - very close to what we expect!

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

[10th Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgU3r.png)

Versions:
R: 4.1.0
xgboost: 1.4.1.1
dplyr: 1.0.7
data.table: 1.14.0

```
library(xgboost)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

set.seed(2)
a <- matrix(runif(1000,0.1234561,0.1234562),
       ncol=1,nrow=1000)
colnames(a) <- c("b") 
d <- abs(rnorm(1000,3*a[,1]))
d2 <- xgb.DMatrix(data = a,label = d)
e <- xgboost::xgboost(data=d2,nrounds=10,method="hist",objective="reg:gamma")

xgb.plot.tree(e$feature_names,e,trees=9)
x <- 2
log((predict(e,a,ntreelimit = 10)/predict(e,a,ntreelimit = 9)))[x]
format(a[x,],nsmall=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the answer, the xgboost team provided it here:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/7294

In short, xgboost converts the input data into float32 before training whereas R uses double by default. Hence, what should be done is convert 0.1234561702 to float32 before running through the model. Doing that gives the value 0.123456173 which now takes the right path.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Comment: Apologies - I've added a short description that summarises the important details from the link (and answers the question).